# What equipment do the Thunderbirds carry?

Tags: costume, thunderbirds

Each member of the team wears the iconic Thunderbirds sash as part of their uniform. Here's Scott:

[image]
[Source](http://www.eagletransporter.com/forum/showthread.php?t=1017&page=131)

He's carrying a pistol (after watching The Uninvited I'm sure it's a weapon) but is there any information on what the yellow and blue "tubes" are on their left hips?

Comment: salt and pepper :-)

Comment: String repair and PVA wood glue

Comment: Tea and whiskey obviously.

Answer (score 2):

Not canon, but I've seen them repeatedly described as [spare barrels for the gun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3AThunderbirds_(TV_series)#Uniform_Question); interchangeable with different kinds of ammunition;

> On the Thunderbirds IR uniforms they had the sash and belt that held a
>   sidearm and two tube thingys (One yellow, one blue) Does anyone know
>   what these tubes were for? I think one might be a radio/microphone (of
>   the silver cylinder on a handle type) as Scott always seemed to
>   produce one from somewhere (like in "The Uninvited"). Des anyone know
>   for sure?
>
> The books refer to different colored interchangeable barrels for their
>   guns. One was stun gas, one was needle darts, one was explosive
>   shells.

If you look at this image, they've got the same ribbing as the barrel of the gun, as well as clearly not being tubular (but rather the same shape/size as the red gun barrels).

[image]